# Elementary number theory: sums of primes and squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that we cannot write:$$5777=p+2a^2$$
where $p$ is a either 1 or a prime and $a\ge0$.
Can you give me a hint?

...i'd better not test all primes :)

Comment: Well, there are only 53 squares to test ...

Comment: Good, but still too many :)

Comment: Needing only to test known finite amount is certainly an enormous advantage. You could not say the same (at least not by the same argument) for the question about $5777=p-2a^2$

Comment: But I don't like brute force :), I prefer other ways, though your reasoning is true

Comment: Why not write a program to test the same? I did it and it worked! No primes! (Python)

Comment: $a$ is divisible by $3$, so brute force can be reduced to testing $18$ squares.

Answer (score 6):

You can establish some properties of $a$, $p$ by considering the values of 5777 modulo some small prime values (3 is a good start).

Comment: I haven't seen congruences yet :)

Comment: I mean this exercise does not request modular arithmetic

Comment: Could you reformulate your hint?

Comment: I fiddled with it a bit more, to avoid congruences: hope this will help:

5777 is ugly, but 5775 has a very nice factorization.  You can rewrite the given as: $p = 5777 - 2a^2 = 5775 - 2(a^2-1)$, so solutions can only exist if $5775$ and $2(a^2-1)$ have no common factors.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was seeking :)

Comment: Now if $a^2$ has the form $3k+1$ we are done, but if $a^2=3k$? (we have $5775=11\cdot5^2\cdot7\cdot3$)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a neat complete solution.  After getting that $a$ must be a multiple of 3, you can eliminate more cases by looking at the other factors (5, 7, 11), but not all.  I got 5 cases left that need special attention :(

Comment: @user247209, what is the source of this problem? Someone else posted the identical question an hour or two later;